# How developers update their applications in Play Store? [Android]

Tags: android, publishing, google-play

I'm considering publishing my application to Play Store. And since I don't have yet developer's account I would like to find some information before. 
E.g. how developers could update their applications? Is it core feature of Play Store and developer should just upload new version of program with new version info maybe or developer should maintain updatable applications manually (by writting some additional code maybe)?
It's quite simple questions but really I can't google nothing about it.

Comment: more information http://support.andromo.com/kb/distributing/how-to-update-your-app-in-google-play

Answer (score 5, accepted):

very simple question indeed.
register to the play store.
finish your app, export it with a signed key, it generates a file.
go to the play store, create new app, put name, decription etc and upload that file.
make changes/improvements/bug fixed to your app, export it with the SAME signed key, it generates another file.
go to the play store, enter the existing app, upload the new file, mark it as active.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy.  You just upload a new version!  Only things to be careful of is that it must be the same application name and you update the version numbers in the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

You have to just make apk file everytime and just upload there, when once you upload new apk, play store will replace old apk with the new one, and users can then update their app.