# Export signed application package

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I'm using eclipse and developing android application. I have an project which is existed on google play store. I change my code and i want to update my app on google play. I click on Android Tools --> Export signed application package. Then i entered my password, everything is good with my code. Finally, i clicked on finish and the step is over. What should i do for next step for updating my app on play store? (I'm saying again, It was an existed project on google play, have keystore file inside of it.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12859243/1554935 And http://stackoverflow.com/a/13349950/1554935

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All i must do is, right click on project--> Android Tools--> Export Signed App Package and then, on Developer Page Android sign up, finally choose your existing app, click on APK and add new APK to Production. After 1 hour, my new apk added on Google Play, and i updated this app.

Answer (score 1):

In order to update your app on Google Play you have to sign your .apk with your **release certificate**. The process is described here: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode . You should not do what you've described above; "Android Tools --> Export signed application package" because doing so you are signing your apk with the **debug certificate**. You need to export your apk as unsigned from the Eclipse and then sign it with your release certificate.

edit:

If you are using Linux then it's something like:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore ~/android-sdks/my-release-key.keystore apk_unsigned.apk release_key
```

and then:

```
zipalign -v 4 apk_signed.apk apk_final.apk
```

Comment: It is a signed project, why should i click on unsigned app? The above links are not same as your solution :s

Comment: I've told you... When you export your apk as signed it is signed with debug certificate (Google Play won't accept that). Once again you need to export unsigned apk from Eclipse and then sing with your release certificate (the same you've signed the app you want to update).

Comment: I will try that and comment you @soulreaver . Thanks.