# How to update existing Android app with new Android app?

Tags: android

I want to know is there any way to update a existing Android app in playstore with my new Android app?

Let me describe: I have a app published on playstore OK with any users. So now I have created a different app with same functionality With different package name and project name.  So now I want to update existing app with new app without losing existing users. Is it possible?

Comment: No, you cant do this, atleast package name must be different

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How developers update their applications in Play Store? \[Android\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859169/how-developers-update-their-applications-in-play-store-android)

Comment: @Mohit this is not a duplicate. He is describing a very specific problem (switching to another package name).

Comment: thank you for you valuable ans.---  now what if i change package name as- Old app..??

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible. You can't change the package name for an already published app. The best you could do is to drive your users to the new published app by adding a banner or link to the updated app inside the old one.

Google Play Store does not allow package names to be changed. It depends on a consistent package name to identify the individual listings.

For a user friendly solution you might add a splash screen to the old app with a link to the Play Store listing of your updated app.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cant do that.
Thats because the package name is a unique identifier. So if you crate an app project in the PlayStore and upload an apk, this project is permanently bond to that package name.

*Question: Was it necessary to change the package name?*

If not, you could keep the existing packagename, change/relayout your app as you desire, and upload the new apk. Your users will then perform a regular update and everything will be kept (ratings, downloads, etc ...)